# How to Update Multi Select Data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multi-select

I am using multiSelect in a form, I need to do CRUD. I have no problems creating the data, my difficulty is in updating the data, because I can not set a default value in multiselect ... Can anyone help me?

I try several times.
[see the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUjFa.png)

Comment: your question is not so clear, maybe provide an example?

Comment: I am going to do CRUD operation using react multi select. I have done the insert operation. But to perform update (when clicking edit button ), items selected during insert operation should be displayed selected. see image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you try using "key" for each item?